# How do I remove elements from a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, linq

Allow me to explain my situation.

I have a table in my database represented in my model by

```
   public Table<LinkDate> dates;

   [Table(Name = "dates")]
   public class LinkDate
   {
       public LinkDate()
       {

       }

       [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
       public string linkguid { get; set; }
       [Column]
       public DateTime dtime { get; set; }

   }
```

which records the day/time that certain IDs were generated. These IDs are associated with one or more files in a table represented by

```
[Table( Name = "links")]
public class AssetLink
{
    public AssetLink()
    {

    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int linkid { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string linkguid { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int fileid { get; set; }

}
```

I'm adding a functionality in my web application where a user can delete all links that are over a certain number of days old. Which means that if any such links exist, I will be deleting rows from both `links` and `dates`.

The action I've started to create is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FlushLinks (string numDaysOld)
    {
        // Deletes all database references to links were submitted over numDaysOld days ago

        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        foreach (LinkDate thisLinkDate in PD.dates)
        {
            TimeSpan thisTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt16(numDaysOld), 0, 0, 0);
            if ((currentDateTime - thisLinkDate.dtime) > thisTimeSpan)
            {
                 // ...
            }

        }

        try 
        {
            PD.SubmitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(ex.Message, "text/html");
        }

        // if here, everything went well
        return Content("Successfully removed all old links!", "text/html");
    }
```

and what I need help filling out is the `// ...` part because I don't know how to, and [can't see any documentation about a way to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table(v=vs.110).aspx), delete rows. What I'm trying to do is the equivalent of

```
 PD.links.Remove(x => x.linkguid == thisLinkDate.linkguid); // need something like this if possible
 thisLinkDate.Remove() // and need something like this if possible
```

What do I need to do?

Also, please let me know about any bugs you see in my procedure.

**EDIT: I think I figured it out by myself:**

```
foreach (AssetLink thislink in PD.links) if (thislink.linkguid == thisLinkDate.linkguid) PD.links.DeleteOnSubmit(thislink);
PD.dates.DeleteOnSubmit(thisLinkDate);
```

If that's wrong, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your foreach loop with this.

```
DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan thisTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt16(numDaysOld), 0, 0, 0);
var delete_list = PD.dates.Where(x => (currentDateTime - x.dtime) > thisTimeSpan)
PD.dates.RemoveRange(delete_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you only need to delete from dates table, and this will cause a cascading delete of all the rows in the links table which reference this date, assuming that the database's referential integrity check is properly configured for these tables.

Comment: How do you configure the tables that way? (Sorry, I'm a n00b)

Comment: This is normally done by the ORM when it creates the tables according to your model. In SQL (which is how the ORM talks to the database) its dones using the REFERENCES or FOREIGN KEY keywords, and cascading deletion (e.g. deletion of the referencing row when the referenced row is deleted) is usually the default behavior.